# How I can use the value in a collection? Firebase

Tags: kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I have this code and need use the documents whit "Profesional" = 3. In this code, i can read the documents but cant use it. i want to launch an activity when "Profesional" = 3.
i mean that in console of Android Studio appear documents with "Profesional" = 3, but i dont know how to use the documents with "Profesional" = 3 in the code, for example, the line .whereEqualTo("Profesional", 3) detect this documents in "Problems" collection, but this appear in the console, i cant use it in the code for launch an activity or other actions.
Sorry for my english!

```
db.collection("Problems")
            .whereEqualTo("Profesional", 3)
            .get()
            .addOnSuccessListener { documents ->
                for (document in documents) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "${document.id} => ${document.data}")
                }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "can't use it?". Please provide screenshots of any errors you're getting or further information about what you're trying to do.

Comment: My guess is that you're trying to access the value outside of the callback/completion handler, which won't work. Data is loaded from Firestore asynchronously, and any code that needs the data has to be inside the callback, be called from there, or in some other way explicitly synchronized to the data loading.